# Why is my cache item not nulled after Cache.Remove call?

Tags: asp.net

I'm trying to remove a specific item from the ASP.NET Cache in order to force a reload.  Something like this:

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(SomeKey);
```

But then I check it immediately afterward, and Cache[SomeKey] is NOT null.  It still contains a reference to this item I want to clear.  Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: When you inserted the item, did you specify a [CacheItemRemovedCallback](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback%28v=VS.100%29.aspx)? If so, what does it do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I figured it out... turns out I had a property in my Watch debug window, which had a side effect of priming the cache.  So even though I was looking at the Cache object it was actually being instantly updated with a new value every time it was cleared.  Embarrassing.